# URL.format is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Please help me out with this error

> TypeError: `URL.format` is not a function
> at C:\Users\lenvo\Desktop\IIT\VideoCall\Site Root\routes\room.js:21:21
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\lenvo\Desktop\IIT\VideoCall\Site Root\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at next (C:\Users\lenvo\Desktop\IIT\VideoCall\Site Root\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
> at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\lenvo\Desktop\IIT\VideoCall\Site Root\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var url = require('url').URL;
const { v4: uuidV4 } = require('uuid');//to generate unique id everytime for every room

//calling upon a random unique id in params
router.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.redirect(`/room/initial/${uuidV4()}`);
});
//rendering to initial page where client settings are done

router.get('/initial/:room', function(req, res){
  res.render('initial',{ room_id: req.params.room });
});
//fetching initial details
router.post('/initial/form/:room', function(req, res){
   var audio = req.body.audio;
   var video = req.body.video;
   var username = req.body.username;
   var room_id = req.params.room;
   res.redirect(URL.format({
       pathname:'/room/${room_id}/',
       query: {
          "audio": audio,
          "video": video,
          "username":"username"
        }
     }));
});
//rendering to room.ejs
router.get('/:room', function(req, res){
  var username = req.query.username;
  var audio = true;
  var video = true;
  if(req.query.audio==undefined){
    audio = false;
  }
  if(req.query.video==undefined){
    video = false;
  }
  res.render('room', { room_id: req.params.room,video:video,audio:audio,username:username});
});

// export
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: var url = require('url'); should do. Why var url = require('url').URL?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`URL.format` should be `url.format`.
Your code should be corrected as follow,

Note that JavaScript is case-sensitive so you can't use URL for URL.

There is another mistake on your code,

```
'/room/${room_id}/'
```

If you use [JavaScript Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) it should be enclosed by the backtick (` `).

Corrected one,

```
`/room/${room_id}/`
```

```
const url = require('url');

res.redirect(url.format({
    pathname: '/room/${room_id}/',
    query: {
        "audio": audio,
        "video": video,
        "username": "username"
    }
}));
```

If `audio` is "mp3" and `video` is "mp4" then your output would looks like,

`"/room/${room_id}/?audio=mp3&video=mp4&username=username"`

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to use url.format not URL.format to use the library and not the browser URL constructor